# How to prevent ipFlood

Tags: php, proxy, ip, limit

### Explanation

There is a website with limits on IP addresses,

but people have started using tools such as:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ipflood/

I believe this tool overwrites headers to "Simulate the use of a series of proxy changing at each new connection."

### Questions

1. Is there any simple way to prevent such abuses with PHP or anything else on the server side? (we have root access to the server and can install packages)
2. Will preventing proxy access to the website also prevent access of such users with such tools?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this tool overwrites headers to "Simulate the use of a series of proxy changing at each new connection."

More specifically, this extension sets fake `X-FORWARDED-FOR`, `VIA`, and `CLIENT-IP` headers on requests. It does not modify the actual source IP of the request.

The workaround is simple. **Don't use the values of those headers** unless your site is behind a load balancer that uses them. (Chances are that it isn't.)

Comment: Thank you, but website is behind CloudFlare and those values are needed i think, what do you think of this method, will it work? http://perishablepress.com/how-to-block-proxy-servers-via-htaccess/

Comment: Even if you are using CloudFlare, you still need to verify that the client IP is a Cloudflare IP, and only read the contents of the origin which Cloudflare sets, which is `CF-Connecting-IP`.